# .htaccess conflictions on different directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

Probably a duplicate question but here goes!

I'm not great at htaccess stuff. I've been using codeigniter and have multiple projects going on currently. I've made a redirect in my public_html to redirect to a directory called "home" right? And in this direct is the base for a codeigniter application where I have another .htaccess file removing the `index.php` from the url for controllers etc.

My question is are these two files conflicting one another? Here's my code:

public_html/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myurl.co.uk$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.myurl/home/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myurl.co.uk$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.myurl/home/$1 [R=301,L]
```

/home/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also another question would be could I display my /home/index.php file on landing on myurl.co.uk without having home in the url?

Answer (score 0):

In my public_html directory htaccess files I have

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myurl.co.uk$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myurl.co.uk$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !home/
RewriteRule (.*) /home/index.php/$1 [L]
```

And I changed my base url to http://www.myurl.co.uk/ whereas before I had http://www.myurl.co.uk/home. Ma bad!